# $\mu=0$ for elliptic curves over number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, iwasawa-theory

Greenberg conjectured that given $E/K$, there always exists $E^\prime/K$ such that $E'$ is isogenous to $E$ and $\mu(E^\prime)=0$. Michael Drinen has shown that for an elliptic curve $E/K$, it is possible that there are no isogenous elliptic curves with $\mu=0$. He says that it is possible when $E$ satisfies some very restrictive hypothesis (which can happen only at finitely many primes, if at all). This was a counter-example to Greenberg's original conjecture. The conjecture is still open for $K=\mathbb{Q}$.

Is there any work which indicates that hypothesis N (as Drinen calls it) is the only obstruction to the conjecture? (ie, if $E/K$ does not satisfy hypothesis N, then Greenberg's conjecture should hold?)

Comment: What is $\mu{}$?

Comment: $\mu$ of the Selmer group of $E$ in standard Iwasawa theory terminology.